# Forcing JScrollPane to scroll by (X) pixels

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane

I have a JScrollPane `scroller` that I would like to make move a specified amount of pixels either vertically or horizontally.

Specifically, I'm making a tile-based game in which the tile panel is wrapped in a JScrollPane that has its scrollbars hidden from the user. I need the code to adjust the scrolling such that every time I call my movePlayer() method in the tile panel, the scrollbar(s) automatically move over by the length of one tile.

Most of my searches so far have only yielded results for `scrollBy` in javascript.

Is there a way to programmatically force the bar to scroll in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`JViewport#getViewRect`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JViewport.html#getViewRect%28%29), [`JViewport#getViewPosition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JViewport.html#getViewPosition%28%29), and [`JViewport#setViewPosition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JViewport.html#setViewPosition%28java.awt.Point%29)

These will allow to adjust the `JScrollPane`'s viewport position.

You can also take a look [`JComponent#scrollRectToVisible`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#scrollRectToVisible%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) which allows to ask that a given area of a component be made visible if it is within a scrollpane/viewport

You can take a look at [Moving a view port over a larger image; JLablel+JScrollPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778717/moving-a-view-port-over-a-larger-image-jlableljscrollpane/19779491#19779491) for example